# Resolve a property in a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor that needs a value from an a config file.  Naively, I would like to do

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${config.file}")
public class MyConfig {
   @Value("${my.property}")
   String myProperty

   @Override
   public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
     doStuffWith(myProperty);
   }
}
```

However, autowiring happens after the post-processer runs, so `myProperty` is always null.  (And it's not clear to me that `@Configuration` classes ever get auto wired.)

Is there some way that I can either manually trigger running autowiring on this component or get the `PropertySources` and manually look up that value?  I expect that I need to write code that does either

```
   magic().runAutowiring(this);
   doStuffWith(myProperty);
```

or

```
   String myProp = magic().getPropertyValue("my.property");
   doStuffWith(myProp);
```

but I don't know which version of `"magic"` exists or how to invoke it.

**Use Case**

The value of the property controls which beans are created.  The code is in a base class, which needs to create differently named beans for each instantiation.  The only way that I found to do that was to with the post processor, so the processor needs to somehow have that property.  The rough sketch of the code is

```
abstract class Base {
   String myProperty;
   abstract String getPrefix();
   abstract Other getOther();
   postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
     if (isValid(myProperty)) {
       MyBean bean = createBean(getOther());
       registerBeanDefinition(getPrefix() + "MyBean", bean);
     }
   }
}

@Configuration
class DerivedFoo extends Base {
  String getPrefix() { return "foo"; }
  Other getOther() { return new FooOther(); }
}

@Configuration
class DerivedBar extends Base {
  String getPrefix() { return "bar"; }
  Other getOther() { return new BarOther(); }
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem of autowiring you cannot do this in a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` as no processing has taken place yet nor are there any bean instances.

Comment: I know that autowiring isn't going to work here.  What I want to know is what can I do instead of autowiring that will work.

Comment: Manually load the properties. Configuration classes are perfectly fine for autowiring but everything that operates on the `BeanFactory` isn't, so things like `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` aren't even when annotated with `@Configuration`. So load manually or explain what you are doing that you think you need this.